# Settar o @Bean DataSource em tempo de execução no Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, runtime, datasource

No `Java` com `Spring Boot framework` os `@Bean` são normalmente settados automaticamente, inclusive o `DataSource` que é o principal da questão, mas também tem como settar o `@Bean` manualmente por código, no caso do `DataSource`, fazendo um método com a notação `@Bean` que retorna um `DataSource` ai é só retornar o `DataSource` do jeito que você quiser.

Mas tem um problema, esse `@Bean` é settado no startup do projeto e eu preciso fazer com que o projeto inicie com este `@Bean` "vazio" e que ele seja settado em tempo de execução, mas já procurei muito e não achei uma forma de settar um `@Bean` em tempo de execução, já consegui fazer o projeto dar startup com o `@Bean` "vazio" só não consigo settar o `@Bean` em tempo de execução.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Bruno, será que o que você quer não é multitenancy ?
Você pode manter a conexão entre dois ou mais bancos e definir qual será usado baseado na requisição que você recebe por exemplo.
Dê uma olhada neste exemplo: https://bytefish.de/blog/spring_boot_multitenancy/

Comment: @hebertrfreitas poderia me explicar melhor, pq a idéia é que ele possa manter a conexão com varios bancos, dinamicamente, sem pré-configuração dos bancos

Comment: Bruno, mas em que momento você saberá as configurações da base de dados, como IP ou dns, porta, usuário, senha, etc ? Vocẽ tem um conjunto de datasources limitado que você precisa consultar ?

Comment: @hebertrfreitas essas configurações viriam de um endpoint que, quando executado, "settaria" esses dados de configuração do banco que vai ser utilizado.

Comment: Bruno, a ideia do multitenancy é você alternar dinamicamente entre um número limitado de datasources, onde possívelmente você já conhece as configurações de acesso.
No seu caso me parece que a aplicação "pode conectar em qualquer lugar".
Nesse sentido, sua arquitetura realmente precisa ser desta forma ?
Se sim, forneça a parte do código onde você está criando o DataSource programaticamente.

Comment: @hebertrfreitas a minha idéia é sim se conectar em qualqer lugar q eu mandar, o numero de datasources pode ser 1 ou 10 (não vai ser mto mas eu não sei quantos vão ser e não tenho as propriedades dos datasources atualmente), o código q eu crio o DataSource programaticamente é resumido numa classe anotada com "@ Configuration" e que tem um metodo chamado "datasource()" que retorna exatamente isso: "DataSourceBuilder.create().username(...).password(...).url(...).build();"